# xamarin form: how to multiply price and qty in listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have listview where i have qty and itemPrice, i need to multiple these two and show totalprice in label. Total price label also in listview here is my code

```xml
<ListView x:Name="mylistview">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout >

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference stepper}, StringFormat='Qty. {0:N}', Path=Value}" 
                           FontSize="11" 
                           TextColor="Black" />

                    <Stepper ValueChanged="stepper_ValueChanged" 
                             Minimum="0" 
                             Maximum="10"         
                             x:Name="stepper" 
                             Value="{Binding Qty}" 
                             Increment="1" 
                             HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.Center" 
                             VerticalOptions="LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"  />

                    <Label Text="{Binding itemPrice, StringFormat='Unit Price - RS. {0:N}'}" 
                           FontSize="11"
                           TextColor="LightGray" />

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="End"  
                           VerticalOptions="End" 
                           Text="{Binding totalprice}" 
                           FontSize="15"
                           TextColor="#da3043" />

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a read-only property in your model for TotalPrice and bind to it

```
<Label Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" ... />

public decimal TotalPrice {
  get {
    return itemPrice * Qty;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks its worked, but have another issue how i can calculate total price on runtime when i change qty value from stepper?

Comment: see Chase's response, it is fleshed out a little more than mine

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `itemPrice` and `Qty` are bindable, so the easiest would be to have a third property and raise its property changed.

```csharp
public class StockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public decimal itemPrice
    {
        get => _itemPrice;
        set {
            _itemPrice = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(itemPrice));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(totalPrice));
        }
    }

    public int Qty
    {
        get => _qty;
        set {
            _qty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Qty));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(totalPrice));
        }
    }

    public decimal totalPrice => itemPrice * Qty;
}
```

**EDIT**

in order to listen for the changes to the items within, you will want your collection to be of type `ObservableCollection`; but since the ObservableCollection doesn't actually notify when items within are changed, you need to further enhance the logic.

```csharp
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ctor
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // only set this once, then just add and remove bits from it.
        Stock = new ObservableCollection<StockViewModel>();
        Stock.CollectionChanged += OnStockChanged;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StockViewModel> _stock;
    public ObservableCollection<StockViewModel> Stock => _stock;

    public double StockSum => Stock.Sum(item => item.totalPrice);

    private void OnStockChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach(var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= StockItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach(var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += StockItemPropertyChanged;
            }     
        } 
    }

    private void StockItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StockSum));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I just learned about `BindingList<T>` which could reduce the code you'd have to write.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: i have just class where i am calculating qty and price `public class LocalItems
    {
[MaxLength(10)]
        public decimal? itemPrice { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(itemPrice * Qty);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: your class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: really appreciate man, thanks a lot its worked, now last thing i need to know if you can help me i have price list in listview which is totalprice, In the bottom of listview how can i display summary price of it? like whole total price....